# image in div doesn't display anything

Tags: css, image, html

i'm trying to insert an image in a div container using css and html, but it doesn't display any image.

html code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="quoteContainer">
 <span class="start_img"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#quoteContainer {
    color: #898989;
    background:#F9F9F9;
    border: solid 1px #ddd; 
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888;
    margin:65px auto;
    padding:15px;
    width:500px;

}

    .start_img {
     background: url(image/img1.png); 
     border: dotted 2px black;
     width:200px;
     height:20px;
    }
```

apart from the img, not even the border shows. i tried using the `<img>` tag in html to insert the image inside the div, that doesn't work either. is there anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The span element, being an inline element, cannot take a width and a height.

Did you try the following?

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="quoteContainer">
 <img src="image/img1.png" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried that. it didn't work. i tried with a <div> tag as well filling the image through css. that didn't work either.

Comment: i figured it out. it was because of the javascript function which was calling the quotecontainer after every 10sec [i had set it that way].

thanks a lot for the pointer, anyway.

Answer (score 9):

That's because a `span` is an inline element by nature, and won't accept arbitrary `width` nor `height` values. You'll have to either make it a `block`/`inline-block` element (Wasn't there a question about that yesterday?) or fill it with content.

It would most certainly work with an `img` element if you set the `src` property.

And, as already said yesterday, if you want your empty elements to display properly throughout browsers, make sure you fill them with at least an `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the span from being inline:

```
.start_img {
     background: url(image/img1.png); 
     border: dotted 2px black;
     width:200px;
     height:20px;
     display:inline-block;
    }
```

And put something in the span.

```
<span class="start_img">&nbsp;</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have in a big content & and they floated give that divs & span float/

When an element cant take width, you have to try add;

```
display:block;
```

to your class/

and for your divs;

```
display:block;
width:204px;
height:24px;
```

but as Pekka said;

```
<img src="#" class="blabla" alt="img" />
```

works fine//

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the image uploaded properly? Double check that and all of your syntax because these all seem like reasonable and sensible explanations. You could just do:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="quoteContainer">
 <span class="start_img"><img src="http://www.whereYouStoreimage.com/link/to/image/imag.png"/></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @lightingwrist, thanks for the reply. but i worked out the answer. please see Daniel Vassallo answer.